# Can I use Apps from the iTunes App Store under Windows?

Tags: windows, itunes

I use iTunes to download podcast. I see there are so many apps also in iTunes.
Would someone tell me, what kind of app are they, and can I use them under windows.
And could you recommend some useful app?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/176326

Comment: @simchona, your link is not applicable here. Amy, your question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question. It will be closed here, but... No, you cannot use apps from iTunes on Windows (except iTunes itself). The apps offered on iTunes are for iPod/iPad/iPhone. If you have one of those, search iTunes for what you need an app for, and then look at reviews of those apps to see which one works best. Good luck. :)

Comment: @KenWhite The OP asked for a "useful app", which is covered by that link.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Apps currently available in the iTunes store are for Apple products such as iPhones. Microsoft Windows PCs are unable to run them.